# =IF(A2-D2,0,IF(B2=D2,0,0)). statement doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m trying to build an IF statement but I can’t get the proper syntax.  I want to total the payments (A PAYMENT TOTALS), if there happens to be multiple payment, and compare them to B TOTALS.

On my spreadsheet under A TOTALS, there should only be a total if there are more than one numbers to total.  On the next column is the A PAYMENT TOTALS where I list the each individual payment; next is the comparison A – B; and lastly is B TOTALS.  My IF statement formula is `=IF(A2-D2,0,IF(B2=D2,0,0))`.  But that statement doesn’t work.  Can you help me?

```
 A TOTALS       A PAYMENT TOTALS     A - B        B TOTALS
 $ 343,471.00    $  1.00               $ 21.00   $ 343,450.00 
 $                 1.00               $                    -     
 $                 1.00               $                    -     
 $                 1.00               $                    -     
 $                 1.00               $                    -     
 $                 1.00               $                    -     
 $                 1.00               $                    -     
 $                 1.00               $                    -     
 $   343,463.00                       $                    -
```

Comment: `A2 - D2` is not really a meaningful logical condition.  Did you intend to compare this difference against something?

Comment: Please post some sample input data with the desired output

Comment: I've tried making sense of your table and your explanation... so `A Totals` is the result of the formula, which only displays if there is number to total.  `Payment Totals` are the individual payments - are these the numbers to total?  `A-B` is a comparison - of what?  _343,471 - 343,450 = 21_ works, but you said `Payment Totals` are the individual payments and possibly the numbers to total - which comes to _8_, not _21_.  Where does `343,463` come into it?  I feel like I almost know what you're after, but the explanation doesn't match the table...

Comment: _there should only be a total if there are more than one numbers to total_  That sentence mentions two columns of totals, but you've got three in  your table and you don't make a distinction between them - `there should only be a B Totals if there are more than one A Payment Totals` or some other combination of totals?

Comment: Thank you guys for getting to me.  I still don't know how to copy/paste my sample data so you can understand where I'm coming from.  My sample data comes out wrong once I try to paste it.  Any help is appreciated so I can truly explain the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the comparison with the result of (A2-D2) in your first test

Comment: Can you post a full example ?